# How to find the controller folder in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-3.1

Not able to see the controller folder in project:

[Please find attached screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPcTM.png)

Answer (score 2):

A project using solely [Razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) won't have any controllers.

(And, there is no requirement for controllers to be in a specific folder: they just need the right base type.)

Comment: Now I got thanks for your response